# Names and Genealogy of Hephtalite rulers?

Tags: central-asia, genealogy

Based on the data I have been able to piece together, I have found the following 3 names:

- **[Khingila](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khingila_I)**, reigned from the mid 5th century. Established the Hephtalite dynasty.
- **Toramana**, reigned end of 5th/early 6th century. Son of Khingila.
- **Mihirakula**, reigned 502-530. Son of Toramana.

What are the names of the kings who reigned after Mihirakula? In particular, what is the name of the [Hephtalite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hephthalite_Empire) king who was defeated by the Turco-Sassanian alliance in the 550s? By the way, were there one or several Hephtalite kings at that time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you one more name for your list. The king defeated by the Turco-Sassanian alliance was [Khushnavaz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khushnavaz). *Probably*. The Timeline seems disputed however.

Reading details on the Sassinid leader at the time, [Khosrow I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khosrow_I) led to this passage:

> According to the medieval Arab historian al-Masudi, Khosrow had before
>   this event campaigned deeply in Hephthalite territory, where he killed
>   their king Khushnavaz (also known as Akhshunvar or Akhshunwar) at
>   Khuttal.

This, according to the [above article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khosrow_I#War_in_the_East), takes place between the formation of the alliance in 557, and another invasion of the Hephthalites In 562 by Khosrow II.

However, the entry for Khushnavaz seems to tell a different story, placing his reign much earlier:

> According to Ferdowsi, some time before 488 Khushnavaz had been
>   succeeded by another king, whose name is unknown.

So the name probably belongs, but a little more research may be required to place him correctly.